# I want to add user points whenever user like the page for Facebook. How can I do this?

Tags: userpoints

After sharing or like a page on Facebook I want to add userpoints in Drupal 7, how can I do this?

Comment: You can do this with Rules if you can somehow make sharing or liking a page on Facebook an event within the Drupal system.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have your users login to your site using Facebook API. There are many modules for it, two I know and seen used are:

- [Facebook Connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect)
- [Facebook OAuth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth)

That's the only real way to know "he" on Facebook is "he" on your site.

Then, Facebook will not push it's data to you. So you have 2 cases:

- Button "like this page on Facebook" on your page - you can detect it being clicked and make a rule for it, as  Patrick Kenny told in his comment.
- Like clicked directly on Facebook - now that's hard. It was [discussed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api) with some apparently good results, and there are [tutorials avaliable](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/).

Last but not least - you need to make sure you grant this bonus only once. If not, users could fabricate points by simply repeatedly liking-unliking your page.